# read an array of objects in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a problem to map an array of objects in an array of objects...

this is my array in back

```
const demoCompletedData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    marketId: "1111-1111-1111-1111",
    title: "Autonomous car",
    picture: "https://th?id=OIP.fdvfdvfdvfdvfd&pid=Api",
    language: "English",
    flag: "",
    completed: true,
    date: "22/01/2019 10:30",
    rate: 9.1,
    categories: {
      de: 1,
      sp: 2,
      uk: 0,
      fr: 1,
      us: 4,
    },
  },
module.exports = demoCompletedData;
```

And my code to read this in front :
fetchDemo

```
  fetchDemo() {
    this.props.demoFetchRequest();
    const { marketId } = this.props.match.params;
    axios.get(`/api/v1/passport-authenticate/market/${marketId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(demo => this.props.demoFetchSuccess(demo))
      .catch(error => this.props.demoFetchError(error));
  }
```

and my return
and my return
and my return
and my return

```
const { demo } = this.props;
```

and my render
and my render
and my render
and my render

```
<p>
            Categories :
            {
              Object.values(`${demo.categories}`).map((category) => {
                return (
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      {category.toString()}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                );
              })}
          </p>
```

How to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Thanks for your help. I want to read 'categories' and map it to show value of 'de', 'fr','us, 'uk' ... but I'm completely lost !

```
{
              Object.keys(demo).filter((x) => { return x === 'categories'; }).map((category) => {
                return (
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      {category.de}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                );
              })}
```

something like that :

```
{category.de > 0 ? `de : ${category.de}` : ''}
{category.us > 0 ? `us : ${category.us}` : '' }
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: No mistake , only [object] [object] in chrome

Comment: Category.toString() strongify all the object.. do you want to display the key (for example DE) or its value (1 for DE) This is what should be in your div, not the entire category object

Comment: hi, thank for your help i would like to do something lke that : 
{category.de > 0 ? `de : ${category.de}` : ''}

Answer (score 0):

Your category is object and you are trying to convert it to string. Try below code.

If you want key then

```
<li>
    {Object.keys(category)[0]}
</li>
```

If you want value then

```
<li>
    {Object.values(category)[0]}
</li>
```